# Equivalent Spring data mongo template query for this containing $each and $position

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have this query and want to use Spring mongo template to fire this query. But Not sure how should I handle $each and $position of mongo with Spring Data.

```
db.data.update(
    //Query
    {"where":"condition"},
    //Update
    {   
        //Set some values
        $set:{"aaa":402.7,"bbbb":6523297.00},
        //Push some value into an inside array at the first place
        $push: { 
            YYYYYY: { $each: [{
                    "time" : 1234,
                    "data" : [ 
                        396, 
                        403.35, 
                        386.5, 
                        401.15, 
                        8370865, 
                        3320159538.15
                    ]
                    } ],
            //
            $position: 0 } 
        } 
     },
     {
        //Update or insert
        upsert: true
     }
     )
```

Currently I have it like this which updates it in the last postiion

```
Update update = new Update();
              update.set("aaa", 402.7);
              update.set("bbbb", 6523297.00);
              update.push("YYYYYY", data.getYYYYYY().get(0));

              Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("where").is(condition));
              mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true),DailyData.class);
```

I understand there is an way to use push using push builder.

PushOperatorBuilder pushBuilder = update.push("YYYYYY");
              pushBuilder.each(data.getYYYYYY().get(0));

but it doesnt have a position property to mention

Answer (score 0):

This is available since 1.7 of spring data from the source.

- Forces values to be added at the given {@literal position}.
       * 
       * @param position needs to be greater than or equal to zero.
       * @return
       * @since 1.7
       */
      public PushOperatorBuilder atPosition(int position) {

  ```
      if (position < 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position must be greater than or equal to zero.");
      }

      this.modifiers.addModifier(new PositionModifier(position));

      return this;
  }
  ```